# What is the term for a 3x3 tile set used to create larger areas?

Tags: 2d, tiles, terminology

What is the pattern/design name of using a 3x3 tileset (usually in a tiled 2D game) that can be used to create larger areas of itself. For example, these:

[image]

([Image source](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-game-programming/9781785281532/ch03s04.html))

I thought it was a "9 tree" or something like that but cannot find it, it is perhaps an uncommon reference.

Comment: I am counting 13 tiles per texture, not 9.

Comment: @Philipp ah yea there it is. Was only interested in the 9 square though :)

Comment: i would have guessed a sprite....nice question, great/informative answers!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A name that will give you actual results in Google is **9-slice**.

Another way to call it and ask Google about it is **9-patch**.

As per [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28435309#28435309) chat discussion, **9-pane** seems to also be used, but the almighty Google will not show you what you need, unless you're into windows or something.

---

Thanks to Kevin and Josh in chat for that.

Comment: 9 Patch was the one I had heard of, thanks for the other ones to have a look at too!

Comment: Heheh, research prior to the question =p

Comment: As a mobile developer i know 9-patch images only as single images with black lines indicating the stretchable part. They are probably named after these. But now I know why they are named like that :)

Comment: I think this answer may be misleading. Most search results for 9-slice/9-patch are about a UI scaling technique which *stretches* parts of an image, not the tiling technique that *selects & repeats* particular tiles. I've elaborated on this distinction in an answer below.

Comment: It does seem more UI related but I once read something relating it to games as a 9 patch so that's what I was after.

Comment: I've also been familiarized with the name 9-grid.

Answer (score 66):

I'd disagree with the accepted answer here.

I'd call this an **autotile**, and *not* a 9-slice

"**9-Slice**" (or 9-patch) is usually used to refer to a system where the content creator slices the image along 4 lines (not necessarily equally-spaced tiles). When rendering a rectangle, the corner slices are displayed at their native size, and the edges/center are stretched (not repeated) to cover the gap.

This is the sense in which Flash, Illustrator, Unity, etc. use the term, so there seems to be good consensus that 9-slice means stretching, not repeating. This is usually used for scaling UI elements like message windows & buttons - and [a Google image search turns up this usage almost exclusively](https://www.google.ca/search?q=9-slice&tbm=isch).

[image: Diagram showing a 9-Slice asset in Flash (left) and how it looks when rendered on a larger rectangle (right)]

[Image from Adobe docs on 9-slice scaling](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/graphic_effects/part03.html)

[image: Diagram showing 9-Slice scaling in game{closure}]

[Image from the game{closure} docs on 9-slice options](http://docs.gameclosure.com/api/ui-images.html)

The term I'm more familiar with to describe a set of tiles that can cover an area of any shape or size is "**Autotile**" (especially in the context of a system that works out/constructs the right tile permutation to use based on adjacency rules, so a level designer doesn't have to hand-pick each tile)

This terminology seems to have been popularized by [RPGMaker](http://blog.rpgmakerweb.com/tutorials/anatomy-of-an-autotile/), which has used a couple of variants on this idea over its generations.

[An image search for autotile shows results which seem much closer to what the question describes](https://www.google.ca/search?q=autotile&tbm=isch), and [other posts on GameDev.StackExchange describe this as "autotiling" as well](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=autotile).

[image: Image describing basic & extended autotile layouts]

[Image from the docs for the Rotorz Tile System for Unity](http://rotorz.com/tilesystem/guide?ref=466570ad-84d7-4a60-b528-378689069efa)

Comment: That's good to know!

Comment: Is it typical for an implementation to squeeze all the inside corners into a single tile? This (and the "basic" version that doesn't have tiles for the sides) seems to depend on the "real" tiling unit being a quarter of the size of the tile.

Comment: @Random832 Those quarter-tile units are how RPG Maker's version works, and quite a few implementations out there seem to be patterned off of this, either for interoperability with existing tiles or just because it's demonstrably useful. I think this reduces the number of tile permutations that need to be explicitly created & occupy space in the tileset. A rough count suggests you'd need about 47 tiles to get the same permutations without subdividing them into smaller units.

Comment: @DMGregory Not *about* 47 but *exactly* 47, I just checked a template I have for 8 direction autotile.

Comment: Wait, why do you need 47, and not just the 13 visible in the image in the original question?

Comment: @Amadeus9 It depends on the granularity and alignment of the autotile. RPG Maker-style autotiles work on tile centers, meaning you can lay a line of terrain 1 tile wide without crossing into adjacent tiles on either side (this means you either need to construct a tile for this case using subtiles, or have a larger pre-generated set to handle this case). The version in the question is corner-based, so the narrowest strip of terrain with borders on both sides is two tiles wide. Effectively, you have fewer distinct tile types but need to use more tiles in combination to get a given shape.

Comment: @DMGregory Oh, gotcha, so for instance a vertical single-tile-wide segment would use the left half of the third tile down on the far left and the right half of the third tile down on the far right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wouldn't consider this type of modular subtile permutation as a requirement for autotiling systems though — corner tiles like those in the question could serve the same role  (though for full coverage you'd also want 2 more tiles for when corners alternate terrain types), as could an exhaustive set of the 47 permutations of the RPG Maker style. It's just an implementation decision about how much texture area you want to author/store for a given degree of level editing granularity.

Answer (score -1):

There are some other names; Wang tiles (dominoes), aperiodic tiling

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile

Also known as tile sets with map editors.

Comment: "Tile set" is a way more generic term and does not refer to the specific type of a tile set in question here.

Comment: Although most terrain tiles used in game tilesets could technically be called Wang tiles, since they'll only match without a seam when placed next to certain neighbouring tiles with corresponding edges, this is a very loose definition and doesn't specifically relate to the particular corner & edge patters OP asks about. (*Any* subset of the tileset shown, including anywhere from one tile to the whole image, is mathematically a set of Wang tiles). Wang tiles and especially aperiodic tiling mainly come up in the context of varying large areas of texture to hide repeats, or procedural generation.

Comment: Wang tiles is a mathematical term.